# Problemas com AsyncTask

Tags: android, asynctask, volley

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição por JSON, juntamente com AsyncTask. Com isso, fiz a chamada do JSON no método doInBackground, porém, o código executa o método onResponse do JsonArrayRequest após a chamada do onPostExecute, e não no momento da sua devida chamada.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvCarregandoLogin;
    private GifTextView gifLogin;

    private String resposta = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lay_login);

        tvCarregandoLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCarregandoLogin);
        gifLogin = (GifTextView)findViewById(R.id.gifLogin);
        tvCarregandoLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        gifLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        new GetTask().execute();
    }

    class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            gifLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvCarregandoLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, Auxiliar.json_url_getEspecialidades, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    String descricao = "";

                    for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            descricao = jsonObject.getString("Especialidade");
                            resposta += descricao + "~";

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    onEspecialidadeIsReady(resposta);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequest(jsonArrayRequest);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            gifLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tvCarregandoLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //fazer alguma coisa com a variavel resposta
        }
    }

    public void onEspecialidadeIsReady(String r)
    {
        resposta = r;
    }
}
```

Classe MySingleton

```
public class MySingleton {

    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context)
    {
        mCtx = context;
        requestQueue = getRequest();
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequest()
    {
        if(requestQueue == null)
        {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(mInstance == null)
        {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public<T> void addToRequest(Request<T> request)
    {
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde está o erro?

Comment: Ele entra no método onResponse depois do onPostExecute. o onPostExecute não deveria ser a última coisa a ser executada?

Comment: Por que está a utilizar uma AsyncTask? *JsonArrayRequest* já é assíncrono.

Comment: Muito provavelmente por falta de conhecimento. Na verdade, o que eu preciso é de apenas exibir alguma coisa enquanto eu faço a requisição do JSON;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O uso da AsyncTask, neste caso, não faz sentido, *JsonArrayRequest* já é assíncrono.

O método `onPostExecute()` está a ser chamado primeiro que o `onResponse()` porque a tarefa executada no `onExecute()` é mais rápida do que a executada pelo *JsonArrayRequest*.

`onExecute()` apenas adiciona o *request* ao *queue* do *Volley*, retornando de imediato.

Altere o código de modo a apenas usar o *JsonArrayRequest*.